# OGNL exception breaking the normal flow when AOP is in place

Tags: struts2, spring-aop, ognl

I am working on Struts2 and spring integrated project.

I am getting OGNL exception as: -

```
Error setting expression 'lookupLicProductSKU.udiPID' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1feae0f'
ognl.OgnlException: target is null for setProperty(null, "udiPID", [Ljava.lang.String;@1feae0f)
```

I also have Spring AOP configured for all the actions to capture few logs. When ever AOP in in action and when I get the OGNL exception specified above, the flow breaks. If I remove the AOP defined in applicationContext.xml, flow runs smooth though there are the above specified OGNL exceptions. I do not understand the reason why this is happening.

Is there a way to make it work with AOP in place? Please let me know.

Comment: What is it you are doing via AOP. Share some code.

Comment: Maybe you need to fix this error.

Comment: I added AOP just for capturing few logs. I have added before and after point cuts.

Comment: I added AOP to do logging using MDC context map. I just add few values to a map in my AOP aspect. Code is here-             
  @After("execution(* com.kumar.swift.myapp.*.action.*.execute(..)) ")
 public void afterActionAspect(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
  
  Map<String, Object> mapObj = SplunkLogger.getSplunkLogger();
  
  mapObj.put("ATT",(System.currentTimeMillis() - (Long)mapObj.get("AST")) / 1000);
  
  
 }

Comment: This is my before point cut- @Before("execution(* com.kumar.swift.myapp.*.action.*.execute(..)) ")
 public void beforeActionAspect(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    
  Map<String, Object> mapObj = SplunkLogger.getSplunkLogger();
  
  mapObj.put("ACN", joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName());
  mapObj.put("AMN",joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
  mapObj.put("AST", System.currentTimeMillis());
  
  
 }

Comment: Putting that much code in comments is useless. Edit the question.

Comment: @user1321648 It couldn't set property because the bean has a null reference. This means you didn't instantiated it in the action or in a collection.